# Failed to load library libOpenCL.so.1, although it exists

Tags: linux, shared-library

I have installed `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` and I try to run a simple OpenCL app, called `vadd`:

```
$ ./vadd
./vadd: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have followed [this](https://tutel.me/c/unix/questions/250975/register.html), and the output looks as follows (I 've kept only the interesting part):

```
$ strace -f -v -s150 ./vadd 2>&1 | fgrep libOpenCL.so.1
...
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```

Well...

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libOpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Dec 18  2015 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

What am I missing here? Is it a problem that `libOpenCL.so.1` is a symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this, so I am posting what I did in case anybody falls in the same pit.

First of all, I *did* have a broken symlink here:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libOpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Dec 18  2015 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

I had OpenCL installed via the [Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/opencl-sdk), and I had messed things up with the installation a little.

**What I found after some digging is that the Intel SDK installation installs the OpenCL shared libraries -having in mind changes in year and versions- in `/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/opencl_compilers_and_libraries_18.1.0.013/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/`**.
For my system (Linux Mint), this is the default location (the only thing you can change during the installation is `/opt/intel/`). In fact, it looks something like this:

```
$ ls -l /opt/intel/system_studio_2019/opencl_compilers_and_libraries_18.1.0.013/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/ | grep libOpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        16 Aug 16 04:35 libOpenCL.so -> ./libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 Aug 16 04:35 libOpenCL.so.1 -> ./libOpenCL.so.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     48216 Sep 21  2018 libOpenCL.so.2.0
```

This means that the only "actual" file is `libOpenCL.so.2.0` and there is a train of symlinks: `libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.2.0`.

Furthermore, I found out that there is a number of symlinks in `/etc/alternatives/`, that look quite OK (basically, what I understood is that they resolve the number at the end of the library name and serve as a middleman in case something changes at the actual libraries - which are all the same in my system, as I pointed out before):

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/ | grep OpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 115 Aug 16 04:35 opencl-libOpenCL.so -> /opt/intel/system_studio_2019/opencl_compilers_and_libraries_18.1.0.013/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libOpenCL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 117 Aug 16 04:35 opencl-libOpenCL.so.1 -> /opt/intel/system_studio_2019/opencl_compilers_and_libraries_18.1.0.013/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 119 Aug 16 04:35 opencl-libOpenCL.so.2.0 -> /opt/intel/system_studio_2019/opencl_compilers_and_libraries_18.1.0.013/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libOpenCL.so.2.0
```

So, the simplest thing I could do was to completely remove the broken symlink above (just `rm`) and create 3 new symlinks, one for each number at the end of the library name, just to be sure:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so libOpenCL.so
$ sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so.1 libOpenCL.so.1
$ sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so.2.0 libOpenCL.so.2.0
```

Now, the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory looks like this and everything seems to work:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep OpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       37 Aug 16 04:47 libOpenCL.so -> /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       39 Aug 16 04:47 libOpenCL.so.1 -> /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       41 Aug 16 04:35 libOpenCL.so.2.0 -> /etc/alternatives/opencl-libOpenCL.so.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

On my case, I just had broken some package.

First, check if your files package are ok.

```
ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL*
```

If you see a RED result like

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        18 abr  5  2017 libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

Red text means the symbolic link is broken, destination missing. Then you need to reinstall it.

Just run

```
sudo apt --reinstall install ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

And do again

```
ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 abr  5  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 abr  5  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43072 abr  5  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

Yeah! No red text anymore. Your `libOpenCL.so.1.0.0` file is present on now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the issue that `libOpenCL.so.1` is a symlink, but that it is a *broken* symlink.

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libOpenCL
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Dec 18  2015 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

The above output shows only the symlink which points to the "real" file `libOpenCL.so.1.0.0`. However, that file should exist in the same directory, but it is not available. That is why the strace output reports `ENOENT` when trying to read the file.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have any idea how to fix this? Purging and reinstalling `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You don't state what distribution you are running. Assuming Ubuntu, make sure you run `apt-get purge ocl-icd-opencl-dev; apt-get autoremove; apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`. That said, if you are running Ubuntu, you shouldn't have seen this problem in the first place.

You might want to look at the package contents for ocl-icd-opencl-dev, as well as the dependencies, there should be a dependency on a library package which should provide the libOpenCL.so.1.0.0 file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink libOpenCL.so pointing to libOpenCL.so.1. That's all.

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ ln -fs libOpenCL.so.1 libOpenCL.so
```